# Headers file doesn't see global variables

Tags: c++

I have 2 two files called main.cpp and Volum_sumar.cpp. I included Volum_sumar.cpp in main.cpp header, but it doesn't see global variables in main.cpp
Can someone tell where is my mistake?

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Volum_sumar.cpp"
using namespace std;
fstream f("Figuri.txt");
fstream d("Dimens.txt");
int n=0;
struct Sfere
    {
      string codsf;
      char culoare [15];
      char material[15];
      float xc,yc,r,arie,volum;
    } sf[100],aux;
int main()
{
  cazul3();
}
```

```
// Volum_sumar.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void cazul3(){
    double volt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     volt=volt+sf[i].volum;
}
cout<<"VOLUMUL SFERELOR INREGISTRARE ESTE DE :  "<<volt<<"cm3"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't include a source file. Ever. Even if it worked it's bad practice. The issue is that you're using `sf` before it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this all wrong.

Like @CruzJean said, by including `Volum_sumar.cpp` directly in `main.cpp`, you are trying to access `n` and `sf` before they have even been defined.

`#include`'ing cpp files in other cpp files is bad practice. You should `#include` only header files. You are supposed to declare shared items in header files that cpp files can `#include` at needed, then compile your cpp files individually, and then finally link the resulting object files together to make the final executable file.

Global variables that need to be accessed across cpp files need to be instantiated in one cpp file and declared as `extern` in other files. The linker will resolve the `extern` references.

Try something more like this instead:

shared.h

```cpp
#ifndef shared_h
#define shared_h

#include <string>

struct Sfere {
    std::string codsf;
    char culoare [15];
    char material[15];
    float xc, yc, r, arie, volum;
};

extern Sfere sf[100];
extern int n;

#endif
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include "shared.h"
#include "Volum_sumar.h"

std::fstream f("Figuri.txt");
std::fstream d("Dimens.txt");
int n = 0;
Sfere aux;

int main() {
    cazul3();
}
```

Volum_sumar.h

```cpp
#ifndef Volum_sumar_h
#define Volum_sumar_h

void cazul3();

#endif
```

Volum_sumar.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "shared.h"
#include "Volum_sumar.h"

void cazul3() {
    double volt = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i) {
        volt = volt + sf[i].volum;
    }
    std::cout << "VOLUMUL SFERELOR INREGISTRARE ESTE DE : " << volt << "cm3" << std::endl;
}
```